# How do I set-up a single point of authentication so that users don't have to log-in on every site outside of the company intranet?

Tags: authentication, claims-based-auth, single-sign-on

As it stands, my users are having to authenticate on every site when outside of our intranet zone. From what I've read, SharePoint should be authorizing at the web application level and not the site collection level, like mine is doing. So what have I screwed up?

Answer (score 0):

What you are referencing has nothing to do with SharePoint.  The "zones" are security boundaries in Internet Explorer.  One of the configuration items you can enable (and is enabled by default in the intranet zone), is the ability to pass credential in the background.

This means you still get asked for username and password - BUT Internet Explorer is simply entering it for you (not quite technically accurate - but hopefully you get the point).

So to further understand what is happening you have to look at what sites are listed in the Intranet zone for access.  How they are entered is very important - because Internet Explorer will match these to understand when it can and can't silently pass your credentials.

So if we configure it for

- https://site/subsite/subsite2  only subsite2 and content under it
  will be approved for using the credentials.
- But if we use https://site/subsite then subsite is covered, and subsite2 would be as well becouse it is under subsite.
- Further is you want all of your domains listed than just go further up.  If you are using fully qualified domain names (fqdn) internally than you can use https://*.mydomain and all your sites will be approved (* is a wildcard character that can be used here).

If it turns out Internet Explorer is not the culprit - you need to dig deeper as there could be multiple reasons.

You might also try to use the browser tools (Press F12 in broswer) to monitor network traffic to see the requests.  I prefer fiddler for this - but the browser tools are a good start.  Look where the 401 HTTP responses are coming from and why.  You may find you are referencing a pictures or some other content in those other sites that users don't have access to. This can cause repeated prompts until the requests fail which then may render all but the denied content.  Depending on what it is - you may or may not notice it on a page.

If your servers are load balanced you need to make sure the load balancing device is not the problem, or that you have a single server somewhere not accepting authentication requests properly.